# compress Base64 using Gzip and get compressed byte in string format

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64, gzip

Here is my Code, i want to return a string instead of a byte

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
        gzip.write(data.getBytes());
        gzip.close();
        byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close();
        return compressed;
```

Comment: The problem is that the output is binary data, not a String. There can be problems with trying to put random binary data into a Sting.

Comment: if you want binary data as string representation (e.g. to send it via http or as an email attachment), you would usually base64 encode it (which increases the size by 33%). Now gzipping an existing base64 (to make it smaller) and then base64 encoding the gzip seems counter productive. So just accept the original base64 and forget about gzipping it.

Comment: You need to say _why_ you want "string format". The other comments here are trying to say politely, "No, you're wrong. You _don't_ want to put binary data directly into a character string."

Comment: @MarkAdler No, I don't say it's wrong. There are reasons to encode binary as text (base64). If I understand the question correctly, the original data is already base64 and he wants to compress it and then get a string (base64) again, and that doesn't make sense. Maybe the original data (before base64 encoding) can be compressed and then just the gzip result will be base64 encoded.

Comment: I wasn’t referring to encoding binary into a larger number of characters. I meant you don’t want to directly recast binary data as a string.